# Loading a 3d model in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, 3ds

i have been trying to load a 3d model in opengl. i have been successful in loading a small model which has 2000 vertices now i am trying to load a model which has 350000 vertices using the same loader but it simply does not show up.
i am using the loader from http://www.morrowland.com/apron/tut_gl.php
and this is the function where i render the 3ds model

```
 void C3dsLoader::Render_3ds()
{

for(int i = 0; i < m3DModel.numOfObjects; i++)
{

    if(m3DModel.pObject.size() <= 0) break;                     

    t3DObject *pObject = &m3DModel.pObject[i];                  

    if(pObject->bHasTexture)                                    
    {                                   
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                                

        glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);                              

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureArray3ds[pObject->materialID]); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                               

        glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);                              
    }

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                                      

    for(int j = 0; j < pObject->numOfFaces; j++)
    {

        for(int whichVertex = 0; whichVertex < 3; whichVertex++)
        {
            int index = pObject->pFaces[j].vertIndex[whichVertex];

            glNormal3f(pObject->pNormals[ index ].x, pObject->pNormals[ index ].y, pObject->pNormals[ index ].z);

            if(pObject->bHasTexture) {

                if(pObject->pTexVerts) {
                    glTexCoord2f(pObject->pTexVerts[ index ].x, pObject->pTexVerts[ index ].y);
                }
            } else {

                if(m3DModel.pMaterials.size() < pObject->materialID) 
                {
                    BYTE *pColor = m3DModel.pMaterials[pObject->materialID].color;

                    glColor3ub(pColor[0], pColor[1], pColor[2]);
                }
            }

            glVertex3f(pObject->pVerts[ index ].x, pObject->pVerts[ index ].y, pObject->pVerts[ index ].z);
        }
    }

    glEnd();
}
```

}

i am using 3ds format.
why is this so?

Comment: Maybe the code from the tutorial you used is using 16 bit numbers somwhere, which overflow and therefore break with large number of primitives.

Comment: oh i see, 
can u provide me with a link where i can have a loader which can load large models, cause all the loader on the internet are like for small 3d models and none of them seems to work

Comment: I don't have 3DS loader at hand, because, quite frankly, I don't use that format in any of my projects. I tend to use a JSON for WebGL and either OpenCTM or a proprietary format in my standalone program projects.

Comment: Have you tried changing the scale? Is the 3DS model drawn at origin? It's always possible that even with 350 thousand vertices that the numbers are ridiculously small, or that instead of it being drawn at 0, 0, 0 that it's drawn somewhere completely off screen. Also, glVertex3f is going to be slow as unless it's in some sort of display list, or a better idea is to try vertex buffer objects. There are plenty of tutorials around.

Answer (score -1):

You may be running out of memory on the card

Anyway display a 350K triangle model using old style glVertex loop, and especially changing the colour on each vertex is going to be very-very slow (as in several seconds per frame)

Before you do much more I would learn about vertex buffer objects. You may also need to reorder your model triangles to minimize the number of colour changes

Comment: hey , thanks for the quick reply.
the format i am using is 3ds so i really dnt know how to render it using glvertex.
any points or links would be appreciated :)

Comment: @If he's using Immediate Mode (glVertex calls) he can't run out of memory on the GPU, because there's nothing uploaded there in form of a contigous block. Also 350k triangles is rather tame. Last but not least, with OpenGL running out of memory means running out of system memory (GPU RAM + CPU RAM + Swap).

Comment: @datenwolf - Don't the textures he is loading cache on the card or is that also copied on each update?

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Textures can be swapped in and out of fast memory as needed. OpenGL provides the function glAreTexturesResident to test, which textures are currently loaded in fast memory.